# Django - Disable editing via view button

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am making a customer portal on django and on the admin panel i have created a list for all the users in the database.

Apart from that i have also added 3 buttons in my table to View, Edit and Delete as shown:
[image: Refer this]

Now the problem is that when i click edit or delete button the code runs as it is intended to do.
But when i click the view button it still allows the person to modify the details. I only want to use it as read-only.

Can someone please help?

This is my admin.py

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from .models import Customer
    from .forms import CustomerForm
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.utils.html import format_html
    
    # Write your models here
    class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        form=CustomerForm
        list_display = ['id','first_name','last_name','profile_picture', 'gender', 'date_of_birth', 'email', 'phone_number', 'address', 'marry_status','country','state','city','view_button', 'edit_button', 'delete_button']
        list_display_links = ['id']
        ordering = ('id',)
    
        def view_button(self, obj):
            return format_html('<a class="button" style="background-color: darkgreen;" " href="/admin/customer_form/customer/{}/">View</a>'.format(obj.id))
        view_button.allow_tags = True
        view_button.short_description = 'View'
    
        def edit_button(self, obj):
            return format_html ('<a class="button" style="color: black; background-color: yellow;" href="/admin/customer_form/customer/{}/change/">Edit</a>'.format(obj.id))
        edit_button.allow_tags = True
        edit_button.short_description = 'Edit'
    
        def delete_button(self, obj):
            return format_html('<a class="button" style="background-color: #ba2121;" href="/admin/customer_form/customer/{}/delete/">Delete</a>'.format(obj.id))
        delete_button.allow_tags = True
        delete_button.short_description = 'Delete'

admin.site.register(Customer, CustomerAdmin)
```

Comment: Add a permission check to your button methods. Also make sure that the underlying model has permission checks.

Comment: it didn't worked :(